# sort a Numpy ndarray of classes and coordinates by min value from left to right

Tags: pandas, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I want to sort a numpy array that contains classes of objects found on an image with corresponding coordinates. Start should be in top left corner of the image and work through row-wise untill bottom right corner.

My numpy array:

```
import numpy as np


columns=['classses','ymin','xmin','ymax','xmax']

arr=np.array([[10.,  0.50835305,  0.47248545,  0.59892374,  0.51885366],
   [11.,  0.36795592,  0.52040386,  0.46757331,  0.56760514],
   [ 4.,  0.24611123,  0.29460225,  0.34236759,  0.34000006],
   [ 2.        ,  0.37274304,  0.38200337,  0.46354109,  0.4273783 ],
   [ 2.        ,  0.510912  ,  0.37931672,  0.59918219,  0.42638448],
   [11.        ,  0.10971789,  0.51647586,  0.20377752,  0.562015  ],
   [ 7.        ,  0.51268667,  0.24481608,  0.59831458,  0.29086089],
   [10.        ,  0.24716213,  0.47549573,  0.33929491,  0.52023494],
   [ 1.        ,  0.37433949,  0.61748177,  0.46359614,  0.65206224],
   [ 7.        ,  0.24870941,  0.24960253,  0.33646214,  0.29458734],
   [11.        ,  0.24345258,  0.51865327,  0.33831981,  0.565395  ],
   [ 8.        ,  0.11206201,  0.33702213,  0.19984987,  0.38336146],
   [10.        ,  0.24955718,  0.6559478 ,  0.34239537,  0.70276546],
   [ 2.        ,  0.24712075,  0.38360605,  0.33835301,  0.42949697],
   [ 4.        ,  0.51084387,  0.29126126,  0.59996665,  0.33353919],
   [ 8.        ,  0.51466578,  0.33362284,  0.60250646,  0.37810257],
   [ 6.        ,  0.510656  ,  0.56336159,  0.59472215,  0.61143786],
   [ 2.        ,  0.1192565 ,  0.69437939,  0.2057956 ,  0.73883325],
   [ 7.        ,  0.11934   ,  0.25181183,  0.20320818,  0.29591617],
   [ 9.        ,  0.51130402,  0.65646565,  0.59214538,  0.70244706],
   [ 3.        ,  0.11690334,  0.56094837,  0.20533638,  0.60812557],
   [11.        ,  0.50439239,  0.51784241,  0.59443074,  0.56629324],
   [ 7.        ,  0.37829998,  0.24856552,  0.46135774,  0.29153487],
   [ 4.        ,  0.37588719,  0.29197016,  0.46272004,  0.33599868],
   [ 1.        ,  0.37316957,  0.57077163,  0.46224919,  0.60553724],
   [10.        ,  0.1145431 ,  0.47239822,  0.20014074,  0.5183605 ],
   [10.        ,  0.37647596,  0.65606439,  0.46242031,  0.70245349],
   [ 1.        ,  0.24754623,  0.61552459,  0.34198812,  0.65568751],
   [10.        ,  0.37339926,  0.47152713,  0.461395  ,  0.52023202],
   [10.        ,  0.37436292,  0.69828469,  0.46418577,  0.74559146],
   [ 6.        ,  0.37082726,  0.42555344,  0.4643003 ,  0.47343689],
   [ 9.        ,  0.5126825 ,  0.69970727,  0.59857124,  0.74693108],
   [ 2.        ,  0.1202545 ,  0.3842268 ,  0.19877489,  0.42925853],
   [ 5.        ,  0.24687886,  0.5643267 ,  0.33911708,  0.61170775],
   [10.        ,  0.12104956,  0.65108246,  0.21425578,  0.69579262],
   [ 6.        ,  0.24587491,  0.42739749,  0.33760101,  0.47690719],
   [ 8.        ,  0.24526763,  0.33704251,  0.33957234,  0.38356996],
   [ 4.        ,  0.1150065 ,  0.29550964,  0.20008969,  0.3379634 ],
   [ 6.        ,  0.514301  ,  0.42620456,  0.59742886,  0.47339022],
   [ 1.        ,  0.24682792,  0.7001856 ,  0.34188086,  0.74008971],
   [ 8.        ,  0.11335434,  0.42906916,  0.19882832,  0.47424948],
   [ 1.        ,  0.11596378,  0.61286598,  0.20856762,  0.64871949],
   [ 8.        ,  0.37103209,  0.33494309,  0.46368858,  0.38201007],
   [ 6.        ,  0.37533277,  0.33500299,  0.46548373,  0.38105384]])
```

Arrays shape is (44,5)

I converted the array to pandas Dataframe, multiplied the values by the actual height and width of the image and found the mean value for X and Y from their min and max values.

```
import pandas as pd


df=pd.DataFrame(arr.copy(),index=None,columns=['classses','ymin','xmin','ymax','xmax'])
df['ymin']=(df['ymin']+df['ymax'])*1080/2
df['xmin']=(df['xmin']+df['xmax'])*1920/2
df=df.drop(columns=['xmax','ymax'])

## now it's rather y and x actually 
df.sort_values(by=['ymin','xmin'])
```

Output:

```
    classses    ymin    xmin
11  8.0 168.432415  691.568246
40  8.0 168.578636  867.185894
5   11.0    169.287521  1035.351226
25  10.0    169.929274  951.128371
37  4.0 170.151943  608.134118
32  2.0 172.275871  780.945917
20  3.0 174.009449  1122.310982
18  7.0 174.176017  525.818880
41  1.0 175.246956  1211.122051

...
```

While the class 8 is located pretty far in top left it's not the lowest value for both X and Y.

I've also tried argsort() and lexsort() and also converting to list and using sorted() with operator.itemgetter() but it brought same results when sorting for both columns.

I thought also about using pop() and argmin() to get the min value of each column and then use the pandas Index to get the corresponding class. But i guess it would be a problem as soon as i arrive at the end of each row.

Thanks in advance!

[Here you can see a (not so accurate) plot of the objects on the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/321yq.png)

Answer (score 0):

One mistake is that if you want it to start from top left to bottom right, then for y-axis, you need to sort by `ascending=False`, while for x-axis, you need to sort by `ascending=True`.

Try `pd.sort_values(by=['ymin','xmin'],ascending=[False,True])`

This will at least give you something in the first row.
However, if you want strictly the left top class, you need first set up some rules to classify that which objects are in the same row. This is another question.